# Redirecting to Controller Action via UploadValues POST doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, http-post

I should call a mail controller's action from another project in the solution, and the Action looks like this: [Controller name is **ServiceMailController**, Action name is **SendNotification**, just like in the caller.]

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SendNotification(string MemberId, string Email, string Name, string RedirectUrl)
        {                
            bool isSent = false;
            try
            {


                Member member = MemberProvider.Instance.GetItem(ObjectId.Parse(MemberId));
                NotificationEmailModel model = new NotificationEmailModel(member);
                model.Email = Email;
                model.Name = Name;
                model.RedirectUrl = "http://example.com/" + member.UserName + "/calismalar";
                UIMailingManager.Instance.SendNotification(model);
                if(UIMailingManager.Instance.SendNotification(model).Success)
                {
                    isSent = true;
                    //comment
                }

            }            
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            }
            return Json(isSent, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And below is my caller code which uses a WebClient.UploadValues to post the data to above action via using "POST" method.

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
                            {
                                var data = new NameValueCollection();
                                data["MemberId"] = item.Member.Id.ToString();
                                data["Email"] = item.Member.Email;
                                data["Name"] = item.Member.Name;
                                data["RedirectUrl"] = "http://example.com/" + item.Member.UserName + "/calismalar";                                  

                                var resp = wb.UploadValues("http://example.com/ServiceMail/SendNotification", "POST", data);

                            }
```

But this gives an error, that has no detailed explanations at all. What would be the reason?

UPDATE: Elmah's error message:

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A public action method
>   'SendNotification' was not found on controller
>   'HintKumasi.UI.Controllers.ServiceMailController'.    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`
>   1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>
> > asyncResult)    at
> >     System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> >     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
> >     Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: Can you post the error message that you're receiving anyway, what's ELMAH saying

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and have the method take in one of those objects:

```
public class Foo
{
public string MemberId {get; set;} 
public string Email {get; set;} 
public string Name {get; set;} 
public string RedirectUrl {get; set;} 
}
public ActionResult SendNotification(Foo foo)
```

The method on your controller is getting an object from your javascript and isn't able to see the properties and hydrate your parameters with those properties. If you tell it to expect and object though, it should be able to parse and populate that object with the values passed.

Comment: I can't send anything to Controller, it doesn't necessary if it is object or another thing.